# Hide or rewrite HTTP response Server Header from SSRS

Tags: security, iis, http-headers, httpresponse, iis-10

I am using SSRS 2016 for my report. And every time I access a report, the response always contains the IIS server information. I want to hide or rewrite this sensitive information from the HTTP response Server header. Is there any way I can do it?

Reporting Services uses Http.sys directly from the server’s operating system to accept requests directed to URLs and ports configured for Reporting Services. This architectural change allows Reporting Services to exist without IIS and provides the same functionality. So, some suggestions to use URLRewrite extension and create an outbound rule in the internet does not help in this case.

Is there any way we can configure to hide/rewrite HTTP response Server header in Reporting Services Configuration Manager?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create an outbound rule to remove Server header like this

```
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="rewrite">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
```

Then you will see the value of Server header being removed.

[image]

Comment: I did apply this solution but it does not work for responses returned from Report Server services (SSRS). Your suggestion works for other web applications which we are seeable in the IIS server. But, the Report Server services I mentioned, they do not display in the IIS. So, I wonder if there is a configuration that I can apply for SSRS to hide that server header.

Comment: @RDeveloper my bad. I ignore the response server is http api not IIS. Have you tried to modify registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableServerHeader(DWORD 32bit) to 2. Then reboot Server and clean browser cache?

Comment: Yes, I did it. But this solution does not help in this case :|